# Wordpress RSS FEEDS for json

Tags: json, wordpress, rss

I just want to ask! if this plugin in wordpress is still working in the newest version?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-feed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it should work just fine, i didn't see anything in the one php file that has been outdated in the new 3.5.1

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply.. Do you mind if you know something another wordpress plugin for json rss feeds can you share some link??.. thanks.. :)

Comment: here is another json rss feed link http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/ and if you like the above answer please accept it